# Regex for number or specific number

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am unable to create a regex expression for below condition.

```
 var1 = '123'
 var2 = '-999'
 var3 = '$##99$#%'
 var4 = '-9999'
 var5 = '-123'
 var6 = '-99'`
```

Conditions:

- accept all integers with max length of 10 digits.
- not accept any characters or symbols.
- accept only '-999' value apart first point(only three digits).
- not accept any integers starting with '-' and other than '999'.

`var1` and `var2` are valid, the rest three are not valid.

This is what I tried so far:

`^[-]?[0-9]{4}$`

`/^\d{1,10}?$/`

Comment: `^\d{1,10}|-999$`

Comment: Have you attempted to create a regex yourself yet?

Comment: I tried this `^[-]?[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: Might put that in the question.

Comment: @AbraCadaver You mean `^(?:\d{1,10}|-999)$`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver . thanks. can you put it in answers?

Comment: @Sweeper: Yeah probably need the group.

Comment: yeah, I spent 1hr for this to build my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check from the beginning of the string for 1 to 10 digits OR exactly -999:

```
^(\d{1,10}|-999)$
```

- `^` start of string
- `(` group
- `\d{1,10}` 1 to 10 digits
- `|` OR
- exactly `-999`
- `)` end group
- `$` end of string

Here's a place to check it: https://regex101.com/r/iMippW/1